# Count wikipedia articles referencing specific wikipedia article with wikipedia-api

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Is there any api request to count all the wikipedia articles that are referencing a specific wikipedia article?

For example: I would like to find out how many times a wikipedia is linked from other wikipedia articles.

Comment: look at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bbacklinks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'backlinks'  property queries to get the list of pages linking to specific article and then count all the results you get.

[Example API query using 'backlinks' for links to English Wikipedia Main Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=backlinks&bltitle=Main%20Page)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly using wikipedia-api but this external tool does a good job at counting all the incoming links quickly.

https://linkcount.toolforge.org/api/